# How select parent of node in any level with its attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I perform XSLT transformation and i use XPATH in templates to get informations from XML, at this point, nothing special, but :

I try to get id of a node "**Aircraft**" when i browse the "**firstEngine**" element and when i browse the "**Engine**" element (and not the "**engines**" element).
I search for a XPATH expression to get "**id**" of the first parent element witch the value of "**xsi:type**" is "**Jet**" no matter of the level of his parent.

I tried without success with this expression :

```
../Aircraft[xsi:type="Jet"]/@id



<Aircraft xsi:type="Jet" id="4">
    <MTOW>0</MTOW>
    <firstEngine>
        <nbFans>2</nbFans>
        <name>turbofanengine</name>
    </firstEngine>
    <engines>
        <Engine>
            <nbFans>2</nbFans>
            <name>turbofanengine</name>
        </Engine>
    </engines>
    <name>jet</name>
</Aircraft>
```

EDIT : #michael.hor257k Your expression works very well, i use Editix to test xpath expessions and it seems to be bugged, I had to restart editix to make it work.
Tks to you !

Comment: "*no matter of the level of his parent.*" The level of *parent* is always one level above the current node. Perhaps you meant *ancestor*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am *guessing* you want to use:

```
ancestor::Aircraft/@id
```

This will work from the context of *any* descendant of `Aircaft`.

I have left out the `[@xsi:type="Jet"]` predicate, since it doesn't seem likely that a node would have more than one `Aircaft` ancestor. But that's just a speculation on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select an attribute so `../Aircraft[xsi:type="Jet"]/@id` should be `../Aircraft[@xsi:type="Jet"]/@id`. That should work with `<xsl:template match="firstEngine"><xsl:value-of select="../Aircraft[@xsi:type="Jet"]/@id"/></xsl:template>`. For the other element you need `../../Aircraft[@xsi:type="Jet"]/@id1`.